# Ingresar datos de tabla html con php a mysql, a través de AJAX

Tags: php, html, mysql, ajax

Vuelvo a subir esto, ya que no he podido solucionarlo y ya me está partiendo la cabeza. Tengo esta tabla que se acumula a medida que quiero añadir datos. Como pueden ver a medida que quiero ingreso datos en el input y el select y le doy añadir, se van formando filas.

```js
var names=document.getElementsByName('datosinternos[]');

function RemoveRow(){
  var table = document.getElementById("tble1");
  var rowCount = table.rows.length;
  //console.log(rowCount);
  
  if(rowCount <= 1)
    alert('No se puede eliminar el encabezado');
  else
    table.deleteRow(rowCount -1);
}

function InsertRow()
{
var TableRow="<tr></tr>";
    for(key=0; key < names.length; key++) {
        var combo = document.getElementsByName('datosinternos[]')[1]; 
        var selected = (key==1)? combo.options[combo.selectedIndex].text : 
names[key].value; 
        TableRow = TableRow.substring(0,TableRow.length-5) + "<td>" + 
 selected + "</td>" + TableRow.substring(TableRow.length-5);
     }
var TrElement = document.createElement("tr");
    TrElement.innerHTML = TableRow;
    document.getElementById("tble1").appendChild(TrElement);
}
```

```html
<script 
 src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>
   <form id="ingresar_datos">
   

 <div class=form-row>
    <div class="col">
    <h6>TEXTO EN COLUMNA 1</h6> 
    <input type="text" placeholder="Ingrese edad" class="input form-control 
    form-control-sm " name="datosinternos[]">
    </div>
    <div class="col">
    <h6>TEXTO EN COLUMNA 2</h6> 
    <select class="browser-default custom-select" name="datosinternos[]">
      <option disabled>Seleccione viaje</option>
      <option value="1">bus</option>
      <option value="2">auto</option>
      <option value="3">tren</option>
    </select>
    </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="col">
    <button type='button' class='btn btn-primary btn-sm' 
    onclick="InsertRow()">Añadir</button>
    <button type='button' class='btn btn-danger btn-sm' 
    onclick="RemoveRow()" >Eliminar</button>
    </div>
    <table class="table table-sm table-bordered table-condensed" id="tble1">
    <thead class="thead-primary "><h5 ><strong>MOVIMIENTOS INTERNOS</strong> 
    </h5>
       <tr>                                                                     
          <th>COLUMNA 1</th>                                      
          <th>COLUMNA 2</th>    
       </tr>                                                       
    </thead>
      <tbody>                                                                
        <tr>                                                                
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
 <input type="button" name="btn_enviar" id="btn_enviar" value="Enviar">

</form>
```

Lo que necesito finalmente es generar una tabla con determinadas filas (ej: 5 filas) y que una vez esté creada, le de click al boton enviar y se ejecute el ajax para enviar estas determinadas filas a mysql.
Tengo entendido que esto se puede hacer a través de un array.

LA OTRA SOLUCION QUE IGUAL ME SIRVE ES:
Que no exista el botón enviar,sino que sólo al rellenar el input y buscar el select, se le de click al botón añadir, se envien los datos hacia mysql
Pero no sé como hacer el ajax y el código php.